# My table is updating but not validated before update in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-validation, laravel-6.2

I'm using Laravel for the first time, version 6.2. My code is working well for updating the table on the DB but it does not validate the data before update. This is the first time I need to validate my form on my own (not the default laravel auth) and I think I'm missing something basic to get it to work.

I'm trying to make the typical change password form with current-password - new password - confirm the new password. Below is my route, my controller and my view.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/cambiarclave', 'Auth\ChangePasswordController@showChangeForm');
Route::post('/cambiarclave', 'Auth\ChangePasswordController@changePassword')->name('cambiarclave');
```

**ChangePasswordController.php**

```php
class ChangePasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function showChangeForm()
    {
        return view('auth.cambiarclave');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'clave-actual' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6'],
            'nueva-clave' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    public function changePassword(request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

        if (!Hash::check($data['clave-actual'], $user->password)) {
            return back()->with('error', 'You have entered wrong password');
        }

        $user_id = $user;
        $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
        $obj_user->password = \Hash::make($request->input('nueva-clave'));
        $obj_user->save();

        auth()->logout();

        return redirect('/ingreso');
    }
}
```

**cambiarclave.blade.php**

```php
<form method="POST" id="change-password" role="form" name="change-password" action="{{ route('cambiarclave') }}"
      novalidate>
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="clave-actual" class="col-md-6 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Clave actual') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="clave-actual" name="clave-actual" placeholder="Password"
                   required autofocus>
            @if ($errors->has('clave-actual'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('clave-actual') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nueva-clave" class="col-md-6 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nueva clave') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="nueva-clave" name="nueva-clave" placeholder="Password"
                   required autofocus>
            @if ($errors->has('nueva-clave'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nueva-clave') }}</strong>
                 </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nueva-clave-confirm"
               class="col-md-6 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirmar nueva clave') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="nueva-clave-confirm" name="nueva-clave-confirm"
                   placeholder="Password" required autofocus>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-50">
                <p class="h5 p-0 mt-1">{{ __('Cambiar') }}</p>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `auth()->user()` is a User you don't need to hit the database again to get the user

Comment: Thanks, i fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss here executing your `validator` method. You should add code like this:

```
$validator = $this->validator($data);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

after

```
$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
```

line in your controller to run validation.

Comment: Hello, I tried this code below $user as you suggested and the validator always goes to fails, redirecting me back with no errors to show in the form and my DB dont update anymore.

Comment: @Sweetmoby For confirmed rule you should specify exact field name as described here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-confirmed because default should be `nueva-clave_confirmation` and not `nueva-clave-confirm`

Comment: Thanks you! That was the problem. The validation work well now. :)